# Использование Getters/Setters внутри класса

Tags: android

Читал документацию на русском про использование [Getters/Setters](http://developer-android.unlimited-translate.org/training/articles/perf-tips.html#GettersSetters) в `Android`. Их необходимо избегать внутри одного класса. Пример плохой практики:

```
class A {
    int a;
    int getA() { return a;}
    void test() {
        int x = getA();
    }
}
```

Правильно ли я понял? В других случаях выходит их использовать желательно(Например если обращаемся к полю вне класса)

Comment: Внутри класса обращайтесь к переменным, как к полям класса - то есть напрямую. Геттеры\сеттеры применяются для обращения к полям только снаружи класса, для более безопасного и контролируемого доступа и в силу принципа инкапсуляции. Внутри класса ничего этого не требуется.

Comment: @pavlofff, а разве  других языках используют такой подход для обращения к полям, как описано в доке?

Comment: Ни разу не встречал такого обращения внутри класса, но я знаю не так много языков, может где то и есть такая практика, хотя она несколько бессмыслена, разве что только если требуется валидация значения, но в таком виде, как у вас - нигде не видел.

Comment: Это я не сам придумал, а написал пример кода, по документации как не нужно делать. Возможно я не так его понял.

Comment: Обращение к полю напрямую "дешевле" вызова метода, если метод ничего не делает, кроме как возвращает значение, то не вижу причин его использовать внутри класса. Кроме того, здесь можно вспомнить еще о ограничении в 65535 методов на проект, такая практика уменьшает число возможных в проекте методов, ничего не давая взамен. Может кто то и прояснит, зачем так делать в том же C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да вы правильно поняли.

> Например если обращаемся к полю вне класса

Я бы перефразировал это по другому:

Геттеры и сетеры желательно использовать вместо прямого обращения других классов к полям данного.